# how to remove a column in dataframe if the specified column values are NaN

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nan

This is my dataframe. I need to delete the row with all the values in d1,d2,d3,c1,c2,c3 are Nan.

```
     no     d1      d2      d3      c1      c2      c3
0   59890   28.4    32.2    31.3    40.7    40.0    39.6
1   55679   NaN     32.8    31.5    37.3    39.2    39.4
2   58900   NaN      NaN    NaN     NaN      NaN    NaN
3   76522   34.0    32.4    32.6    45.4    NaN     46.9
4   89525   32.7    31.9    32.0    44.1    44.4    46.1
... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...

The expected output:
     no     d1      d2      d3      c1      c2      c3
0   59890   28.4    32.2    31.3    40.7    40.0    39.6
1   55679   NaN     32.8    31.5    37.3    39.2    39.4
3   76522   34.0    32.4    32.6    45.4    NaN     46.9
4   89525   32.7    31.9    32.0    44.1    44.4    46.1
... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Exclude a specific column from pandas dropna](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64843289/exclude-a-specific-column-from-pandas-dropna)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [dropna()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html) parameters:

```
df = df.dropna(subset=['d1','d2','d3','c1','c2','c3'], how='all')
```

Alternatively, if it's the first column you don't want to include:

```
df = df.dropna(subset=df.columns[1:], how='all')
```